# Discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, vector-lattices

Suppose that $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, we define
$$
S(M)=\left\{c_{1} \mathbf{v}_{1}+\cdots+c_{m} \mathbf{v}_{m}: c_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
where $\mathbf{v}_i$ is the i-th row of the matrix $M$.

Is $S(M)$ a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$? It seems that the distance between two elements cannot become arbitrarily small as long as we do not consider a sequence of infinitely many basis vectors. Is that correct? So, it appears to be a discrete subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $$M=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\\pi\end{array}\right)$$

For any integer $n$, we can divide the half open unit interval $[0,1)$ into intervals $A_r:=\left[\frac rn,\frac{r+1}n\right)$ for $r=0,\ldots,n-1$.

Consider the values $[k\pi]$ (where $[\,\, ]$ denotes fractional part of), for $k=1,2,3\ldots$. These values all lie in the integer span of $1,\pi$: $$[k\pi]=k\pi-\lfloor k\pi\rfloor1.$$

Further $[k\pi]\in[0,1)$ so for each $k$ we have $[k\pi]$ in some $A_r$.  Eventually we will have $[k_1\pi]$ and $[k_2\pi]$ lying in the same interval $A_r$, with $k_1\neq k_2$, by the pigeonhole principle.

Thus $[k_1\pi]-[k_2\pi]$ lies in the span of $1,\pi$ and has size less than $\frac1n$.  Note that $[k_1\pi]-[k_2\pi]\neq 0$ as $\pi$ irrational implies that $0$ cannot be written as a non-trivial integer combination of $1,\pi$.

Thus elements of the span of $1,\pi$, may be arbitrarily small.

Comment: How do we show that $[k_1\pi]-[k_2\pi] < \frac{1}{n}$? Does the pigeonhole principle allows us to conclude that since for every $k$ they lie in a different $A_r$?

Comment: @JohnyDow There are infinitely many $k$ and only finitely many $r$ so we know that distinct $k$ will fall into the same $A_r$.  We know they are close together (less than $\frac1n$ apart) because the length of $A_r$ is $\frac1n$.